# How do I add extra info to Blueimp File Upload

Tags: file-upload, callback, blueimp

I am using this code to load existing images from the directory, then to also hopefully add the uploader's username:

```
// Load existing files:
$.ajax({
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0]
}).done(function (result) {
    $.each(result.files, function (index, file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/fileinfo.php?mode=getname",
            success: function(data) {
                file.user = data;
            }   
        });
    });
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, null, {result: result});
});
```

What this does is go to my database and load the uploader's username from the database and add it to the result object. If I console.log(result.files) I get this:

```
Array[5]
0: Object
delete_type: "DELETE"
delete_url: "/fileupload.php?file=Desert.jpg"
name: "Desert.jpg"
size: 845941
url: "http://mydomain.com/files/963/Desert.jpg"
user: "Demo.User"
...
```

and so on for the other files - which looks correct. (note the addition of the 'user' element.)

So I want to display the file.user information in my templated table. I add a new row that looks like this:

```
<td class="uname"><span>{%=file.user%}</span></td>
```

and nothing displays. What is wrong with my logic? Does something need to change in the code somewhere as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this approach won't work. Instead, I do an ajax call to load the ids from the database BEFORE this construct. Then I just use array values.